# 'Assert' and 'require' atomicity while internally calling another contract

Tags: solidity, assert

```
contract one{

unint number;

function saveNumber(unint _number){ number = _number; }

}

contract two{

function callOtherFunctionAndAlsoTransferFunds(){

oneContract = one('contractaddress');
oneContract.saveNumber(6);
assert(msg.sender.transfer(10000000));


}    
}
```

The line I am concerned about is

```
 assert(msg.sender.transfer(10000000));
```

- Can I do this ?
- If this throws an exception, will the internal transaction that called contract one also be reversed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are interested in checking the return value from ether transferring operation you should use `send` method instead of `transfer` which is meant to throw an exception on failure.

```
 assert(msg.sender.send(10000000));
```

Referring to your question:

> If this throws an exception, will the internal transaction that called
>   contract one also be reversed ?

Yes, all of the state changes are going to be reverted when transaction throws an error. This is done regardless of whether the methods are called inside one or several contracts.